# xcode run app on device after delay 5 minutes

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone 3GS (jailbroken), I use Mac mini Mid 2009 (OS X 10.8.5) with official Xcode 5. It builds, compiles normally and whenever it runs app on device, it takes around 5 minutes delay to run. I mean when xcode notifies signal 'Running on xxx device', I immediately see my app plash screen, it's OK, but then I have to wait 5 minutes to xcode run the first code on appFinishLaunching on AppDelegate. Why is it? It make me tired for waiting while running.

I bring my phone to another mac mini, it works ok, this bug not happens. I'm quite sure that it doesn't cause by xcode 5.

Can anyone meet this and any solutions?

Comment: How does another device on the same mac go?

Comment: I don't know, I just have my phone, :|

Comment: Try to borrow one. Did you try 'rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'

Comment: @Jasper Blues, do you mean I have to try deleting this folder. :)

Comment: Yes it's a build products directory. Try deleting and rebuilding. Sometimes it helps.